# Sharing screenshot using Instant Markup Interface does not call didSelectPost()

Tags: ios, swift, screenshot, share-extension

I'm using iOS share extension and it is working fine if I open Photos app, share any image to my host app. However, it is not working if I take screenshot, open Instant Markup Interface(the one which shows in window after we take screenshot), and tap on share to select my host app. When I tap on post, didSelectPost() is not getting called. Do I need to do something special in this case?